# Sass maps output

Tags: sass

I have a map of styles for each header elemenet:

```
$header: (
    h1: (
        color: black,
        font-size: 13px
    ),
     h2: (
        color: black,
        font-size: 10px
    ),
    .....
```

I wish to output these like so:

```
@each $label, $map in $header {
    color: map-get($map, color);
    font-size: map-get($map, font-size);
}
```

The above gives a syntax error. I'm not sure what's wrong with it.

Also is it possible to spit out the color and font size for each h tag?

Answer (score 0):

In your current code, you are just trying to print the css properties and forgetting to print the selectors(h1, h2...) which is why it's throwing syntax error.

Here is the updated SASS,

```
@each $label, $map in $header {
  #{$label} {
    color: map-get($map, color);
    font-size: map-get($map, font-size);
  }
}
```